# What does “She’s a ten and I am a 5” mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrases

If you have seen the movie [*She’s Out of My League*](https://imdb.com/title/tt0815236/), in one scene they give everyone marks: “She’s a ten, and I’m a five. How can we be together?”

What do these numbers mean?

Comment: Compare with the film *10* - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078721/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Ten out of ten* means 'full marks' in a test, competition or as an estimate of a person's quality. According to the brief synopsis of the film, the male lead considers the woman he loves to be 10/10 for attractiveness, but himself to be only 5/10 (only moderately attractive).

Answer (score 0):

Someone mentioned the movie "10" but that was released  over 40 years ago, who's got the time to watch that in order to get the reference? I'd say compare it to [**Tinder**](https://www.techadvisor.com/how-to/software/tinder-3515013/). A 10 is someone who's "hot" while a person classified as a 5 is closer to "cold"… profiles are then [swiped right](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/swipe-right-left) (yes) or left (no)? and if two users like each other's photos and profiles they are "matched".

*[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She%27s_Out_of_My_League)* summarises the plot of "She's Out of My league"

> Molly asks Kirk out a few days later and he agrees. Stainer predicts their relationship will fail, **he refers to Molly as a "10", and Kirk as a "5"**, saying that is too big a difference.

To be [out of someone's league](https://www.lexico.com/definition/league) means not belonging in that group. Lexico's third definition matches the movie's pretext.

> A class or category of quality or excellence.
>
> - ‘*Cynicism aside, **she's way out of his league**.*’
> - ‘*So, have you ever had a crush on someone a little **out of your league**?*’

[*Cambridge Dictionary*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/someone-something-is-out-of-someone-s-league) says

> someone or something is too good or expensive for someone to have:
> “She was the most beautiful girl in school, and I knew **she was out of my league**“.

The **rating** of bodies and attractiveness out of ten is still popular in American High Schools, albeit that kind of classification has spread across the world or very nearly.

Comment: With the movie "10" I think the age is the point -- rating attractiveness from 1 to 10 has been a steady thing for 50 years. It's part of the language now.  Not a good part, but people understand things like "she's a civilian 6 and an army 9".